# execCommand copy async alternative for Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, execcommand

`document.execCommand('copy')` can be used inside the resolve function of a Promise except for Firefox.
Every modern browsers like Chrome, Opera, and even Safari allow async copy up to 1 second.

I want to improve the user experience and copy data following a calculation in the clipboard.

**Is there a solution to copy the result of a Promise with Firefox in one click?**

Here a snippet working with Chrome

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="copy(genPwd)">copy</button>
<script>
    function genPwd() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            resolve('toto')
        })
    }
    function copy(p) {
        p().then(function(result) {
            console.log('create fake text area');
            var fakeTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
            fakeTextArea.setAttribute('readonly', '');
            fakeTextArea.value = result;
            document.body.appendChild(fakeTextArea);
            fakeTextArea.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a solution, to ask for "clipboardWrite" permission, check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard

Comment: clipboardWrite permission is for a webextension right?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, missed that.

Comment: perhaps wait for the experimental [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API)